# 'method' object is not sub scriptable in python

Tags: python, constraint-programming

I am implementing Minimum Remaining Values of CSP in python.And I got some errors.

I run with python3 and also with python2 interpreter .

```
def select_unassigned_variable(assignments, csp):
    variables = [var for var in csp.nodes()
                     if var not in assignments.keys()]
    if not variables:
        return None
    return min(variables, key=(lambda var: (len(csp.nodes[var]['domain']))))
```

I got the error like:

```
return min(variables, key=(lambda var: (len(csp.nodes[var]['domain']))))
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1):

change to something like

```
key=(lambda var: (len(csp.nodes()[var]['domain']))))
```

Comment: Still error.list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Thats because `nodes` is (apparently) a list, and you have not defined `var` as an integer. It seems the only reason it has a value at all is because it hasn't been trash collected yet has left over value from the list comprehension.